# how button can be address on annotationView to perform an action in iphone?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, annotations, mkmapview

I want to add button in `annotationView` in `mapkit` in iPhone for performing an action on clicking that button. How can I perform action on clicking that button? and how to create that button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem while ago and [THIS](http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/corelocation/add-a-button-to-an-annotation/) tutorial solved the problem.
If you are not sure take a look at source project provided on the site.